# Pointer as index value in for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, pointers

I'd like to use a few `for` loops in C and use common index for these. I want to use pointer, because I will be able to free it later.
I thought about something like:

```c
uint8_t *p = malloc(sizeof(uint8_t));

for (*p = 0; *p < 255; *p++)
{
  // Instructions...
}

// A few loops...

free(p);
```

But this code doesn't work as I want. How can I fix it?

PS I'm a beginner in C's pointers.

Comment: In the code as shown, you're not accomplishing anything you couldn't have done by declaring an ordinary variable `uint8_t i;`.  There are uses of dynamic memory allocation, but this isn't it!

Comment: Also, using an 8-bit type as an index variable is usually a bad idea, and is a rather frequent source of subtle bugs.  Is there a reason you're trying to use `uint8_t` here, instead of plain `int`?

Comment: Just change *p++ to (*p)++, it should work fine.

Comment: I used uint8_t because I wanted to save memory. I will check what will happen if I use `int`, wait a second

Comment: In general, for individual variables like that, using a type smaller than `int` uses *more* memory, runs more slowly, introduces bugs, and wastes your time.  It's a loss in almost every way.  My advice to you is: just use `int`!

Comment: Also, if memory is tight, *definitely* use an ordinary variable here.  Don't mess around with `malloc`.  Your pointer variable `p` will take two, four, or eight bytes, on top of the memory you allocate.  `malloc` will use more memory for bookkeeping than the one byte you ask it to allocate.  Then there's the memory for the instructions to call `malloc`, to check its return value (which you left out), and to fetch from and store to the pointed-to value `*p`.  You're burning memory right and left here, not saving it!

Comment: If memory is really that tight, you need to learn how to use the tools on your platform which will tell you, objectively and after the fact, how much memory (code and data) your program is *actually* using.  Don't make decisions based on how much memory you think something should use, or on what someone told you.  Memory usage can be counterintuitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved the problem. My code:

```c
uint8_t *p = malloc(sizeof(uint8_t));

for (*p = 0; *p < 255; (*p)++)
{
  // Instructions...
}

// A few loops...

free(p);
```

Thank you all for your answers!

Comment: I'm glad to know it works, but it would be easier to read, easier to write, faster, use less code, and use less data if you were to simply write `uint8_t i;` and use `i` everywhere instead of `*p`.  You are also skating on thin ice here: it is very easy to write a loop that runs forever, when you try to use an 8-bit variable to count to 256.  (You're saved by the fact that you're only counting to 255.)

Comment: I said it would "use less code and use less data if you were to simply write `uint8_t i;`", but you would likely save even more if you changed it to plain `int i;`.

Answer (score 2):

By this line:

```c
uint8_t *p = malloc(sizeof(uint8_t));
```

You're allocating memory that is suitable to hold ONE `uint8_t`. You shouldn't touch any other addresses after p because you didn't  allocate them. You may need to do the following:

```c
uint8_t *p = malloc(255 * sizeof(uint8_t));
```

The previous line allocates memory that can hold 255 `uint8_t` instead of just one. That way, you can access addresses from `p` to `p + 254`.

Comment: It works, but is too hard to understand for me. I will go back to normal index variable. Thanks!

Comment: malloc simply takes the number of bytes you need from the RAM. You code says to the operating system: "Hey Windows (or linux or mac), give me a memory that can hold uint8_t value". But you actually want 255 values. that's why I multiplied the sizeof(uint8_t) by 255. This way, I'm saying: "Hey Windows, give me memory that can hold 255 uint8_t values.".

Answer (score -1):

Syntax of malloc is :

```
int * p = (*int )malloc(sizeof(int);
```

You have to first convert the data type into pointer

Comment: No, casts on `malloc`'s return value are not required, and are disrecommended by most C experts.